# Flutter - How to run our app in the background while another app takes the foreground?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to run my application in the background while another app takes the foreground? Can the app still fetches data from API and go to the foreground if the condition met?

For example,
I open my app first -> Login -> Do something -> then I can press the home button or back button to send the app to the background so I can run Google Map in the foreground but my app still fetching the data from API -> If the data is matched with the condition, the app can go up to the foreground and show some message.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

On Android this feature supports by using [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). In your case you can start new service on Flutter side by calling native method on Android side. For do it, declare a common `MethodChannel` (Flutter has great documentation, read more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)) on Flutter and Android sides and work with this channel for pass a data and call methods between cross and native platforms. Also you can run service as another process (it is useful when you need to do something when user closed your app). How to use services for Android described in [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) and in [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) tutorial.

iOS doesn't support this because it's has limitations for background work.

Comment: Thank you very much. You really save me. Could you please give me some code examples for this method?